# Scroll not working properly for RecyclerView inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Actually I am having 2 Problems

1st. Scroll is not working properly, sometimes when we scroll a very small distance in a particular direction and leave the touch, it scrolls very fast till the end of that particular direction i.e., upside or down

2nd. I want the title of the custom Toolbar to be shown only when its collapsed and when its expanded the title should be hidden

Here's the XML Code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/imageone"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appBarLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favourite"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"

    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

[image]

Comment: Where is activity (fragment) code?

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution for this. I am facing similar issue.

Comment: @Gaurav Nope. I have stopped using coordinator layout with recyclerview when I faced this issue. Today I again tried it with updated SDKs, still same issue. Instead I am using [ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) these days

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer given by Kuldeep the solution to the first problem is given below:

To remove the bad scrolling behavior of RecyclerView just set this attribute on your RecyclerView:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

or to do this dynamically you can use:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Note: if you use FloatActionButton inside your CoordinatorLayout it will not execute hiding animation when your recyclerview scroll

Answer (score 0):

// hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
       boolean isShow = false;
       int scrollRange = -1;

       @Override
       public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
           if (scrollRange == -1) {
               scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
           }
           if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                //set your title when you scroll up
               collapsingToolbar.setTitle(title);
               isShow = true;
           } else if (isShow) {
               //title will disappear when you scroll down 
               collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
               isShow = false;
           }
       }
   });
```